# Calling method with array or arguments using QueuedConnection

Tags: multithreading, qt, invoke, metaobject

I want to call arbitrary slot of QObject in other thread.

I have:

```
                           |  Arguments:    | Can use QueuedConnection?
QMetaObject::invokeMethod  |  fixed number  | YES
qt_metacall                |  array         | NO
```

I want:

```
<something>                |  array         | YES
```

I don't want to do things like duplicating invokeMethod code based on the number of arguments.

Where to get invokeMethod that accepts array of arguments or how to make qt_metacall queued?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a queued signal/slot connection?

Comment: I want user to call methods with arguments by name. Currently it's a bunch of interconnected slots and signals, but adding each method requires adding things in about 6 places in the code. I want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can either:

1. write a signal with the same default parameters as the slot you want to call, connect it to the slot with `Qt::QueuedConnection` and call the signal with `qt_metacall` and your array, or
2. write a `QObject` derived class that:

   - takes your parameter array as parameter for its constructor, and stores it internally,
   - calls `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` in the constructor with `Qt::QueuedConnection` to invoke a slot without parameter which will call `qt_metacall` with the stored parameter array before deleting the `QObject`.

Internally Qt uses the 2nd method but with a internal class: `QMetaCallEvent` (in [corelib/kernel/qobject_p.h](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/corelib/kernel/qobject_p.h#line249)) and [`postEvent`](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.7/src/corelib/kernel/qmetaobject.cpp#line1632) instead of a signal/slot connection.

Answer (score 0):

Working around by creating array initialized by GenericArgument:

```
QGenericArgument args[] = {
            QGenericArgument(), ....... ,QGenericArgument(),};

for (int p = 0; p < parameterTypes.count(); ++p) {
    QVariant::Type type = QVariant::nameToType(parameterTypes.at(p));

    switch(type) {
    case QVariant::String:
        args[p] = Q_ARG(QString, obtainTheNextStringArgument());
        break;
    // the rest needed types here        
    }
}

mm.invoke(object, Qt::QueuedConnection, args[0], args[1], args[2], args[3], args[4], args[5], args[6], args[7], args[8],args[9]);
```